# change work item buttons on Team Web Access home page

Tags: tfs

How can you control what work items types appear as buttons on the Team Foundation Server 2012 Team Web Access home page?  I have deleted some WITs and created new ones.  The new ones only appear in the 'more' drop down list.  I would like them to appear as buttons.

[image: TFS 2012 Team Web Access home page WIT add buttons]

When you look at these WITs in VS, it appears that the ones shown on the home page have a ! icon, but the ones in the 'more' dropdown have a checkmark icon.

[image: VS work item icons]

I looked at all the xml config files available in witadmin, but can't find anything that ties these WITs to any type or category that indicates this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try adding it to the RequirementsCategory using witadmin importcategories?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd273721.aspx

In TFS 2013 those buttons are gone anyways...

Comment: Thanks so much.  That did the trick.  I had already deleted my RequirementsCategory since I had removed the backlog item and saw no relation between that and anything I needed.  And I'm sad to hear those buttons are not there in 2013.